# Deploying a Client/Server application on Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, client-server, mybatis

I have one stand alone client server application.
I want to move it to Spring MVC so that it can be deployed on some server (eg. TOMCAT etc).

I've referred to many Spring MVC tutorials etc but couldn't get any idea how I can deploy my own app.

The application outline is as followed.

**SERVER** accepts data from client and processes it, checks whether data is already in there or DB or not, if not it inserts it in DB as well as writes it on a particular file based on ID specified by client.

**CLIENT** sends just randomly generated data as of now.

Now what I want to do is create web pages where I can, by clicking on a button, initiate the client and send data to the server as well as show the response on a client page (eg. connected, data received, data inserted in DB, data already exists in DB etc.)

**_ I'm badly stuck here and don't have any idea how to move forward so please guys help me out here. _**

I can post the code if required in editing.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: what is the specific problem ?  The reference docs are a good place to start : http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/

Comment: Is there already an application to deploy? So are you planning to re-write the standalone application to a web based application using Spring MVC or just deploying an existing application?? You can deploy a project to TOMCAT by simply copying the war archives to tomcat's deployment folder.

Comment: @NimChimpsky : yeah but the thing is it already confused me a lot.!!!
and i'm just a begginer..

Comment: what are you confused about ? There is no specific question here. The krams tutorials are also good : http://krams915.blogspot.com/p/tutorials.html

Comment: @MiMee: exactly i want to rewrite the application in SPRING MVC so that i can make it available online.. and dont have any war archives for same.. its just simple POJ code..!!

Comment: @NimChimpsky: yeah...  just opened that site..!!! and to be honest i am just not getting anything from the tuts i found so i posted the question here..!!

Comment: How about the spring sample apps : https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/? All the info is there, not a lot else anyone can do really ....

Comment: Then may I suggest you to start with HTTP Servlet API, XML and HTML, and then continue to Spring MVC the last. It will be better to master such a complicated framework with a strong basic. Here is a good tutorial for servlet: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19159-01/819-3669/6n5sg7avg/index.html

Comment: hey guys thanks for the suggestions..
and Mi Mee i guess starting from scratch would be a better idea but i have time constraints.. :(
anyway thanks again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to deploy a web-application you need to create a .war file. In the eclipse IDE you simply chosse "run as" / "run on server".
You should also specifiy the spring-version, your build system (ant or maven).

Using spring-sts (as plugin or sts-workbench) you would have templates which will setup your project correctly.

There 
so many options, my suggsestion for a quick start would be: create a project with 
maven by entering on the command line

```
mvn archetype:generate
```

then select the archtype (project template)

```
spring-mvc-jpa-demo-archetype
```

run

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

import the project into eclipse, perfom a build and choose "run on server"